# How to fix the marker and move the map and update location

Tags: android-studio, google-maps

I made an activity which shows the current location and update the location whenever I drag the marker but I need to make a custom marker which should befixed at the centre and whenever I move the map it should update the location in textview. I am using inbuilt marker now so don't need to specify layout. Here is my Code:

````
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.internal.GoogleApiAvailabilityCache;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.UiSettings;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FieldValue;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.karumi.dexter.Dexter;
import com.karumi.dexter.PermissionToken;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionDeniedResponse;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionGrantedResponse;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionRequest;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.single.PermissionListener;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;

public class currentLocationMapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener, BottomSheetDialog.BottomSheetListener, GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Location mLocation;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener locationListener;
    private long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 55000;
    private long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 50000;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private MarkerOptions markerOptions;
    private Marker marker;
    private LatLng latLng, latlng1;
    private boolean isPermission;
    private View mapView;
    private ImageView backbtn;
    public TextView changebutton;
    private TextView cityTextView, AddressTextView;
    public RelativeLayout relativeLayoutcl;
    private ImageView gps;
    private Button saveLocation;
    FirebaseAuth fAuth;
    String userId, address,state, postalcode, country ,city, district, scity, sstate, spostalcode, scountry, saddress, sdistrict;
    Double mLatitude, mLongitude, slatitude, slongitude;
    TextView savecurrentlocation;
    int i = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_current_location_map);
        cityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cityname);
        AddressTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.addressText);
        saveLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirmlocation);
        savecurrentlocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.save);

        if (requestSinglePermission()) {
            // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
            mapView = mapFragment.getView();

            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();

            locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            checkLocation();
        }
        backbtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backbtnmap);
        backbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        gps = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.locationgps);
        relativeLayoutcl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeinvisible);
        changebutton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.changebtn);
        changebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog();
                bottomSheetDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "BottomSheetDialog");
            }
        });
        savecurrentlocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FirebaseFirestore mFireStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                userId = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                if (i == 1){
                    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                    map.put("City", city);
                    map.put("Address Line 1", address);
                    map.put("State", state);
                    map.put("Country", country);
                    map.put("District", district);
                    map.put("Postal Code", postalcode);
                    map.put("Latitude", mLatitude);
                    map.put("Longitude", mLongitude);
                    CollectionReference documentReference = mFireStore.collection("users").document(userId).collection("addresses");
                    documentReference.add(map).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentReference>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentReference> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                Toast.makeText(currentLocationMapActivity.this, "Saved location first", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else {
                                Toast.makeText(currentLocationMapActivity.this, "Sorry bro", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                }
                if (i == 2){
                    Map<String, Object> smap = new HashMap<>();
                    smap.put("City", scity);
                    smap.put("Address Line 1", saddress);
                    smap.put("State", sstate);
                    smap.put("Country", scountry);
                    smap.put("District", sdistrict);
                    smap.put("Postal Code", spostalcode);
                    smap.put("Latitude", slatitude);
                    smap.put("Longitude", slongitude);
                    CollectionReference sdocumentReference = mFireStore.collection("users").document(userId).collection("addresses");
                    sdocumentReference.add(smap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentReference>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentReference> stask) {
                            if (stask.isSuccessful()){
                                Toast.makeText(currentLocationMapActivity.this, "Saved location second", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else {
                                Toast.makeText(currentLocationMapActivity.this, "Sorry broo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }

            }
        });


    }


    private boolean checkLocation() {
        if (!isLocationEnabled()) {
            showAlert();
        }
        return isLocationEnabled();
    }

    private void showAlert() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setTitle("Enable Location")
                .setMessage("Your Locations Settings is set to 'off'.\nPlease Enable Location to" + "use this app")
                .setPositiveButton("Location Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(myIntent);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });
        dialog.show();
    }

    private boolean isLocationEnabled() {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) ||
                locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    }

    private boolean requestSinglePermission() {
        Dexter.withActivity(this)
                .withPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse permissionGrantedResponse) {
                        isPermission = true;

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse permissionDeniedResponse) {
                        if (permissionDeniedResponse.isPermanentlyDenied()) {
                            isPermission = false;
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permissionRequest, PermissionToken permissionToken) {

                    }
                }).check();
        return isPermission;
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        if (latLng != null) {
            mMap.clear();
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).draggable(true).title("Hold and drag marker to change location").draggable(true));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 18F));
            mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
            final View locationButton = ((View) mapView.findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1")).getParent()).findViewById(Integer.parseInt("2"));
            if (locationButton != null)
                locationButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            gps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mMap != null ){
                        if (locationButton != null)
                            locationButton.callOnClick();
                    }
                }
            });
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) mapView.findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1")).getParent();
            View compassButton = parent.getChildAt(4);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) compassButton.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams1.setMargins(0, 180, 0, 0 );

        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) !=
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        startLocationUpdates();
        mLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLocation == null) {
            startLocationUpdates();
        } else {
            //Toast.makeText(this, "Location not Detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }

    private void startLocationUpdates() {
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL)
                .setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) !=
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        cityTextView.setText("Searching....");
        AddressTextView.setText("fetching location....");
        saveLocation.setEnabled(false);
        saveLocation.setAlpha(.3f);

        String msg = "Updated Location: " +
                Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + "," +
                Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
        //Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        try {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
            i = 1;
            city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
            state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
            postalcode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
            country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
            address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
            district = addresses.get(0).getSubLocality();
            mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
            mLongitude = location.getLongitude();
            if (city == null){
                cityTextView.setText("Searching....");
                AddressTextView.setText("Fetching location....");
                AlertDialog.Builder alertdialogbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(currentLocationMapActivity.this);
                alertdialogbox.setTitle("Unable to fetch location");
                alertdialogbox.setMessage("Try to search address manually");
                alertdialogbox.setPositiveButton("Retry", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        startLocationUpdates();
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                alertdialogbox.setNegativeButton("Manual Address", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AppHome.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert1 = alertdialogbox.create();
                alert1.show();
            }
            else {
                cityTextView.setText(city);
                AddressTextView.setText(state + "(" + city + ")" + "," + " " + country + " " + postalcode);
                saveLocation.setEnabled(true);
                saveLocation.setAlpha(1f);
            }
            if (state == null){
                AddressTextView.setText("(" + city + ")" + "," + " " + country + " " + postalcode);
            }
            if (postalcode == null){
                AddressTextView.setText(state + "(" + city + ")" + "," + " " + country);
            }
            if (country == null){
                AddressTextView.setText(state + "(" + city + ")" + "," +  " " + postalcode);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onButtonClicked(String text) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
        cityTextView.setText("Searching....");
        AddressTextView.setText("fetching location....");
        saveLocation.setEnabled(false);
        saveLocation.setAlpha(.3f);

    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
        try {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> saddresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(marker.getPosition().latitude, marker.getPosition().longitude, 1);
            i = 2;
            scity = saddresses.get(0).getLocality();
            sstate = saddresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
            spostalcode = saddresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
            scountry = saddresses.get(0).getCountryName();
            saddress = saddresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
            sdistrict = saddresses.get(0).getSubLocality();
            slatitude = marker.getPosition().latitude;
            slongitude = marker.getPosition().longitude;
            if (scity == null){
                cityTextView.setText("Searching....");
                AddressTextView.setText("Fetching location....");
                AlertDialog.Builder alertdialogbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(currentLocationMapActivity.this);
                alertdialogbox.setTitle("Unable to fetch location");
                alertdialogbox.setMessage("Try to search address manually");
                alertdialogbox.setPositiveButton("Retry", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        startLocationUpdates();
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                alertdialogbox.setNegativeButton("Manual Address", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AppHome.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert1 = alertdialogbox.create();
                alert1.show();
            }
            else {
                cityTextView.setText(scity);
                AddressTextView.setText(sstate + "(" + scity + ")" + "," + " " + scountry + " " + spostalcode);
                saveLocation.setEnabled(true);
                saveLocation.setAlpha(1f);
            }
            if (sstate == null){
                AddressTextView.setText("(" + scity + ")" + "," + " " + scountry + " " + spostalcode);
            }
            if (spostalcode == null){
                AddressTextView.setText(sstate + "(" + scity + ")" + "," + " " + scountry);
            }
            if (scountry == null){
                AddressTextView.setText(sstate + "(" + scity + ")" + "," +  " " + spostalcode);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}```
````